# Displaying object on FormPanel in ExtReact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extjs, extreact

I'm new to ExtReact tools and I'm having issues with displaying an object in a FormPanel at least using the record property. As per [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/6.7.0/modern/Ext.form.Panel.html) if I set the record property with my object the values should display on my form. Instead I find myself needing to call `this.form.setValues()` from `componentDidUpdate()`.

I've created an example in [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/?extreact#view/editor&fiddle/2qe0). In the example I've added a Load Values button instead of `componentDidUpdate()` just to show that the values are not being loaded into the form when `record={values}` is set on the FormPanel and only when calling `this.form.setValues()`.

Answer (score 0):

record parameter must be instance of Ext.data.Model, instead of Object ({}) value.

[Here is an example fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/?extreact#view/editor&fiddle/2qn0)